# R cron script does not auto-refresh httr-oauth token

Tags: r, oauth, cron, httr

I have an R script running via cron on a cloud server. It uses the googledrive package to read some files on Google Drive. There is an .httr-oauth token in the directory. This has been running fine for some time, auto-refreshing the token as needed, but recently has hung up asking for authentication in the browser, which of course is not available since this is a cronjob.

I've tried following this:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/217952868-Generating-OAuth-tokens-for-a-server-using-httr

including generating a token on my desktop (which required going thru the whole browser thing), and then copying it over to the server, but the job still always gets hung up asking for browser authentication.

What else should I be looking at to try to figure out what's wrong, or how can I fix this and get the process back to automatically refreshing again?

Comment: See documentation for `drive_auth` by using `?drive_auth`. Instead of launching a browser, you can use google's service account instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a service account.

Comment: Then you need  to create one using your google cloud console. Otherwise, I cannot think of another way.

Comment: OK, thank you- I don't have admin privileges so I don't think this will work for me.